# Load ftrscanapi.dll in vb.net application

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, fingerprint

I am trying to integrate the ftrscaniapi.dll file in my vb.net application that help in reading the fingerprint from the Futronic FS80 device. But I am getting error as "Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is valid assembly or COM Component".

So can anyone help me to overcome this issue or if you have any alternative solution to get the fingerprint from the device then please let me know.

Comment: It wasn't made to be used like that, you have to use pinvoke.  The company publishes an SDK that promises to make it easier to use VB.NET, it is not directly downloadable from their web-site.  Give them a call.

Comment: Is this a free SDK.? Or can you please give me the exact details.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't add this DLL as a reference. You have to declare as "DLLImport".

Here I found a code in C#.

http://fingergraph.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/FingerGraph/Scanner/Device.cs

I used http://converter.telerik.com/ to convert to VB.Net and works for me.